# Date range error when trying to change the design

Tags: error, design, magento-1.8

I'm test running Magento 1.8.0.0 (community) and I've stumbled upon an error when trying to change designs. First, I changed the design from the default to "default/iphone", and it worked like a charm. However when I tried to change the design to a custom one, I got the following error:

> Your design change for the specified store intersects with another one, please specify another date range.

I keep getting the same error even if I try to change the design to one of the default included ones (e.g. "default/modern").

Clearing the `design_change` table solves the issue, but I can't mess with the database everytime I want to change the design. Is there a non-programmatic solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you are trying to set design configuration settings via the `System > Design` menu rather than in the `System > Configuration > Design` section. If so it's an understandable mistake, but the `System > Design` settings are intended for date-based design changes over and above the theme setting hierarchy in `System > Configuration > Design`.

You can see a quick explanation at http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/custom-design-fallbacks-in-magento.html, which has some diagrams and explanation of how the fallback hierarchy can be established.

Magento, Inc. has provided a thorough document on design architecture in Magento as well: [http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/ [PDF]](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/)